# Spawn entity error while trying to launch my robot in gazebo. I am using ros2 humble

Tags: gazebo, ros2, slam, mobile-robot, ros-humble

I am using the package from github repository:
https://github.com/kosigab/salford_robot

While launching the given launch file with the given robot as in the repo, there is no problem it works fine. [This is the given launch file](https://github.com/kosigab/salford_robot/blob/main/launch/display.launch.py) code and [this is the given URDF](https://github.com/kosigab/salford_robot/blob/main/src/description/salford_robot_description.urdf).

While trying to change the robot with my custom robot, it shows `spawn_entity.py` error. My robot is there in the rviz but in gazebo even though the world is there, there is no robot.

my launch file(edited):

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import PathJoinSubstitution
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch.actions import TimerAction

def generate_launch_description():

   
    pkg_share = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='salford_robot').find('salford_robot')
    default_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'src/description/my_robo.urdf')
    default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'rviz/urdf_config.rviz')
    world_path=os.path.join(pkg_share, 'world/floor_plan3.sdf'),
    
    robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': open(default_model_path, 'r').read()}]  # Read URDF directly
    )
    
    joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher',
    )
    
    rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', LaunchConfiguration('rvizconfig')],
    )
    spawn_entity = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='gazebo_ros',
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        arguments=[
            '-entity', 'sam_bot_description', 
            '-topic', 'robot_description'],
        output='screen'
    )
    robot_localization_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
       package='robot_localization',
       executable='ekf_node',
       name='ekf_filter_node',
       output='screen',
       parameters=[os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config/ekf.yaml'), {'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')}]
    )

    slam_toolbox_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            os.path.join(launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='slam_toolbox').find('slam_toolbox'),
                         "launch",
                         "online_async_launch.py")
        )
    )

    nav2_bringup_launch = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            os.path.join(launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='nav2_bringup').find('nav2_bringup'),
                         "launch",
                         "navigation_launch.py")
        )
    )

    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        

        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='use_sim_time', default_value='True',
                                            description='Flag to enable use_sim_time'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='model', default_value=default_model_path,
                                            description='Absolute path to robot urdf file'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='rvizconfig', default_value=default_rviz_config_path,
                                            description='Absolute path to rviz config file'),
        launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', world_path], output='screen'),                           
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        spawn_entity,
        robot_localization_node,
        rviz_node,

        TimerAction(
            period=15.0,
            actions=[slam_toolbox_launch]
        ),
        # TimerAction(
        #     period=25.0,
        #     actions=[nav2_bringup_launch]
        # ),
    ])
```

My urdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This URDF was automatically created by SolidWorks to URDF Exporter! Originally created by Stephen Brawner (brawner@gmail.com) 
     Commit Version: 1.6.0-4-g7f85cfe  Build Version: 1.6.7995.38578
     For more information, please see http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter -->
<robot
  name="sam_bot_description">
  <link
    name="iso_boat">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-1.38777878078145E-17 -0.000588763440924456 0.077836789738661"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="1.64494635327615" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0155578151555619"
        ixy="-4.08431314394383E-19"
        ixz="5.21546474069026E-19"
        iyy="0.0212137440033421"
        iyz="-3.40539003827603E-05"
        izz="0.0277147834390728" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/iso_boat.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/iso_boat.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link
    name="Ltyre2">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="2.77555756156289E-17 2.77555756156289E-17 0.0704595420433916"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.175547753699789" />
      <inertia
        ixx="8.64642854248281E-05"
        ixy="-1.27054942088145E-21"
        ixz="5.79378815621321E-21"
        iyy="8.6464285424828E-05"
        iyz="-2.90933958498696E-22"
        izz="0.00011563060090041" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/Ltyre2.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/Ltyre2.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="tyre2"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.08 -0.097 0.03032"
      rpy="1.5707963267949 -0.0393424149683315 0" />
    <parent
      link="iso_boat" />
    <child
      link="Ltyre2" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="0"
      upper="0"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="Rtyre2">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.0212404579566084"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.175547753699789" />
      <inertia
        ixx="8.64642854248279E-05"
        ixy="-2.71275499171093E-37"
        ixz="3.7223762559446E-21"
        iyy="8.64642854248279E-05"
        iyz="-1.71312973292452E-37"
        izz="0.00011563060090041" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/Rtyre2.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/Rtyre2.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="tyre4"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.08 0.1887 0.03032"
      rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="iso_boat" />
    <child
      link="Rtyre2" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="0"
      upper="0"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="lidar_gear">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0.00227272727272732 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.00863937979737194" />
      <inertia
        ixx="8.07859360873399E-07"
        ixy="1.60588755438802E-23"
        ixz="2.64697796016969E-23"
        iyy="8.14850594524853E-07"
        iyz="-2.00731221062913E-23"
        izz="8.07859360873399E-07" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/lidar_gear.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/lidar_gear.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="lidargear"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.0595154464958421 0.00587675965139767 0.215"
      rpy="1.5707963267949 0 1.3924186886556" />
    <parent
      link="iso_boat" />
    <child
      link="lidar_gear" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="0"
      upper="0"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="lidar">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0.00945945945945947 -2.77555756156289E-17"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0581194640914112" />
      <inertia
        ixx="1.52819201426015E-05"
        ixy="5.04691646561411E-22"
        ixz="0"
        iyy="2.54665354481623E-05"
        iyz="-4.13172750491015E-22"
        izz="1.52819201426015E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/lidar.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/lidar.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="lidar"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.000484553504158158 0.00587675965139778 0.215"
      rpy="1.5707963267949 0 1.14194493121528" />
    <parent
      link="iso_boat" />
    <child
      link="lidar" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="0"
      upper="0"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="castor">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="3.46944695195361E-18 -1.38777878078145E-17 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.00176714586764426" />
      <inertia
        ixx="3.97607820219958E-08"
        ixy="0"
        ixz="0"
        iyy="3.97607820219958E-08"
        iyz="-3.29273669950096E-56"
        izz="3.97607820219958E-08" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/castor.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://salford_robot/meshes/castor.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="whell1"
    type="fixed">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.124098121773513 0.001540084182452 -0.00916817798423553"
      rpy="1.5707963267949 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="iso_boat" />
    <child
      link="castor" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 0" />
    <limit
      lower="0"
      upper="0"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
</robot>
```

I have proper files for meshes and all. Can anybody help me solve this error?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Mr.Meeee. You say `it shows spawn_entity.py error`, but you don't give the error. Please *edit your question* to include the error you're seeing.

Comment: I Solved the Issue, you have to add Gazebo Path to the python Launch file , but i don't exactly know why it works. ``` gazebo_path = SetEnvironmentVariable( name='GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH', value=[ EnvironmentVariable('GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH', default_value=''), '/usr/share/gazebo-11/models/:', str(Path(get_package_share_directory('package_name')).parent.resolve()) ] ) ```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23761)